# Redirect user to html page from asp login control when no internet connection

Tags: asp.net, authentication, redirect, html5-appcache

I am using the application cache to save pages offline and have set a FALLBACK: so that, if the user accesses any page on my site which isn't in the appcache, they are  redirected to Home.html. The only point at which this doesn't work is if the user has the Login.aspx page open before they lose connection. If they then select the login button they are sent to the  standard 'There is no internet connection' page rather than my Home.html page.

Can I get the login button to send the user to my Home.html page when they have no internet connection? I am using a standard asp login control on my login page. I tried setting the following in `system.web` in my `web.config` file:

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="Home.html" mode="On">
 </customErrors>
```

but that seemed to have no effect. Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: Does the login page have a manifest attribute?

Comment: No, the login page doesn't have a manifest attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Application Cache to support fallback behavior for the login control.  The login control issues an HTTP POST, and [only HTTP GET is supported](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/offline.html#the-application-cache-selection-algorithm).

You could write your own login page that uses a GET, but that means the user name and password would show up in the URL, which is not a very good idea, [even over HTTPS](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/).

Perhaps you could issue the login request within an iFrame, or using AJAX, and use Javascript to navigate to the fallback page if it fails.

By the way, application cache support has been [deprecated](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/application-cache-api-has-been-deprecated/), so maybe you should move away from this solution.

Comment: Thanks. I had suspected that this might not be possible so it is good to have it confirmed. The user will get to my Home.html page if they refresh the 'There is no Internet connection' page so all is not hopeless. I had noticed that Application Cache has been deprecated. Despite its shortcomings, it is working well for me. What are the recommended replacement technologies?

Answer (score -1):

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"/>
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"/>
</customErrors>

As you saw here, you can invoke the page to be redirected if these two errors occur. I hope that it helped
```

Comment: These settings don't matter if there is no connection.

Comment: Actually, he can add "503 error status code" instead of "404" and "500"  which is the code returned for no connection.

Comment: Returned over what? The connection that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, 503 means the website has fallen over which is a bit different - I've seen that error more times than I would like!